# How to keep a TextView center aligned within a RelativeLayout with mutliple TextViews

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-relativelayout, layout-gravity

I have this `RelativeLayout` with two `TextView`s, One with `center` aligned and the other `end` aligned,

```
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/size_10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/size_10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title_count_text"
                    fontPath="fonts/title_bold.ttf"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@color/background"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text="(0)"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/size_5dp"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/size_5dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/textColorGrey"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/size_18dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title_text"
                    fontPath="fonts/title_bold.ttf"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text="This is a Sample Test"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/textColorGrey"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/size_18dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </RelativeLayout>
```

Looks something like this, Please find the image below,

[image]

Its working fine with small text length, but if I increase the text length it will overlap the counter text, Obviously the `title_text` is rendered after the `title_count_text`,

But if I add `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/title_count_text"` property to the  `title_text` and change the width to match parent to make this TextView center aligned. the `title_text` will loose the center gravity.

Will look something like this, Please find the second attachment below

[image]

Although it might not be visible, but yeah its now shifted about the width of counter text to the left,

What i want to achieve is to preserve the center alignment of the `title_text`and when the text length is greater and it reaches the start of counter text view, it should clip the text and append `...` to the end,

Any kind of help will be totally appreciated,

Thanks

**TL:DR Not only center aligned but also needs to clip when it meets the counter text view, if text length is greater.**

Comment: use linear layout and  give weight 1 to 1st text view , max lines 1

Comment: @Redman is right! No need to use relative layout, you just have to use liner layout and using its weight property you can make your textview in center.

Comment: @Redman Can you please post it as an answer,

Comment: You want "This is a sample Text" text as center aligned ?

Comment: Yea @Ankita, Not only center aligned but also needs to clip when it meets the counter text view, if text length is greater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like then **remove the padding** of your **Relative layout** and add padding to **title_text Textview**

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_count_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="(0)"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/size_5dp"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/size_5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/textColorGrey"
        android:textSize="@dimen/size_18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="This is a Sample Test wehatb the  are u dongibng wjkl"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/textColorGrey"
        android:textSize="@dimen/size_18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Finallyyyy!!... What magic did you use? lol :D Have been pulling my hair for the past 5 Hours. Thanks buddy.

Comment: @Sanoop i am just trying to resolve your issue nothing else

Answer (score 1):

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/title_text"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/title_count_text"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                fontPath="fonts/title_bold.ttf"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="This is a Sample Test"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/textColorGrey"
                android:textSize="@dimen/size_18dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
```

I added the following two lines to your second text view to get the behavior you described:

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/title_count_text"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
```

You may have to play around with the ellipsize settings though.

Comment: Yea.. Exactly.. How to make the ellipsize work.. Thats the ultimate question.. :(

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned above in above comment , use `LinearLayout` with width `matchparent` , orientation `horizontal`.
Inside linear layout take 2 text views ,1st `TextView` width 0dp and weight 1, 2nd `TextView` width wrap content

Comment: Tired the same, Still the first textView is Shifted towards Left,

Comment: @Sanoop if you want ellipsize to work use `android:inputType="text"` in xml attribute

Comment: Nop, Cant see any difference. :(

Answer (score 0):

Update `title_text` as following:

```
               <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title_text"
                fontPath="fonts/title_bold.ttf"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/title_count_text"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="This is a Sample Test"
                android:textColor="@color/textColorGrey"
                android:textSize="@dimen/size_18dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
```

The following 3 attributes are main to added:

```
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/title_count_text"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
```

Also, remove :

```
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/size_10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/size_10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_count_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/background"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="(0)"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/size_5dp"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/size_5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorGrey"
            android:textSize="@dimen/size_18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="This is a Sample Test"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorGrey"
            android:textSize="@dimen/size_18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Noo.. @Ankita aa .. it doesnt work, what this bascially do i assign the allotted space for both textViews, it wont clip the textview. :( :( Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score -1):

Try this and let me know,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    android:weightSum="1"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:text="test"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:text="0"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Down voter! can you plz comment the reason before applying solution?Do not downvote without applying  your logic here..

Comment: Nop Doesnt work @Radhey Have tried this but the text lenght is greater the title_Text  is not clipping.

Comment: add android:singleLine="true" , to the textview.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, Totally appreciate it, there are a lot of users whose agenda is to degrade and self promote. +1 for your effort!! Happy coding..

Answer (score -1):

> Try this:-
>
> Add android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/title_count_text" and  android:maxLines="2" to the TextView with id "@+id/title_text". It worked for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp10"
android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp10">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_count_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dp5"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/dp5"
    android:text="(0)"
    android:textSize="@dimen/dp18"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/title_count_text"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:text="This is a Sample Test This is a Sample Test This is a Sample Test This is a Sample Test"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="@dimen/dp18" />

</RelativeLayout>
```